# How to share ssh keys, so multiple devs can work on one private repo

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys, private-key

I am new to ssh (not the ssh login and user permissions) but more like github ssh.

I have a project on my github, which is in private mode and I have to developers that I would like 
to work with. So, far the only way to work on this private repo is to hand them the email/password to my 
github account, which we all know is not going to happen.

So, since I haven't worked on team projects, I don't know the exact steps I have to do to grant them access, 
and which exact steps they should then take to access it.

So, I think the first thing to do: [Checking for existing SSH keys](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys/) via gitbash

```
foo@desktop /c/xampp/htdocs
$ ls -al ~/.ssh
total 13
drwxr-xr-x 1 zorg 197121   0 Feb  8 21:49 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 zorg 197121   0 Mar  4 18:03 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 zorg 197121 344 Feb 10 16:48 known_hosts
```

My site is located at `/c/xampp/htdocs/website` but I am running the key generation at `/c/xampp/htdocs` because I understand it makes
no difference (citation needed)

after this, assuming that I have no previously generated keys (since I don't see anything starting with *.pub) I went to 
[Generating a new SSH key and adding it to the ssh-agent](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/)

So, after generating the keys and copying the keys to clipboard via `clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

I went to  https://github.com/username/project/settings/keys

and added the keys.

Now, my question is, assuming what I have done is so far correct, how do I allow these three collaborators access to my repo?

Comment: You don't share keys. You add multiple keys (one per developer) to the repository.

Comment: Ideally, though, each developer forks the project in their *own* account, and you collaborate via pull requests between the forks.

Comment: @chepner You mean, I would create another key the same way as I did before? and If I have 10 people, I would create 10 keys?

Comment: That's right. Although, you still need to find a way to distribute the new keys to the other developers (or treat the keys as something you use only once, until the developer can generate and upload his/her own key). It's probably much simpler to have each developer fork your repository, rather than grant them access to it directly.

Comment: Hmm, this is all a bit confusing to me, for example they have no paid plan in github, and if they fork it, then it will show on their public list of repositories. Also, if I send the the ssk key by mail, do they add just add it in their profile and get access to the private repo?